# OutOfMemoryError while doing docx comparison

Tags: java, docx4j

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OutOfMemoryError while doing docx comparison using docx4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308299/outofmemoryerror-while-doing-docx-comparison-using-docx4j)

When I compare 2 documents which are around 10kb i get below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.topologi.diffx.algorithm.MatrixInt.setup(MatrixInt.java:123)
at com.topologi.diffx.algorithm.DiffXFitopsy.length(DiffXFitopsy.java:188)
at com.topologi.diffx.algorithm.DiffXFitopsy.process(DiffXFitopsy.java:238)
at com.topologi.diffx.Main.diff(Main.java:323)
at com.topologi.diffx.Main.diff(Main.java:310)
at com.topologi.diffx.Main.diff(Main.java:228)
at com.topologi.diffx.Docx4jDriver.diff(Docx4jDriver.java:170)
at org.docx4j.diff.Differencer.diffWorker(Differencer.java:320)
at org.docx4j.diff.Differencer.diff(Differencer.java:298)
at CompareDocuments.main(CompareDocuments.java:117)
```

Please help me in resolving this issue. I increased the JVM memory to 1400, even that's not working out.