# Undeclared namespace with o:allowincell in docx4j Differencer.diff() call

Tags: xml-namespaces, docx4j

When comparing the results of a document transformation process to the original with docx4j, we're getting the following error for one of our test cases:

`com.topologi.diffx.xml.UndeclaredNamespaceException: The namespace URI "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office for allowincell" has not been mapped to any prefix.`

I eliminated the possibility of errors introduced by the tranformation process by comparing the original document to itself using this method (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347961/obtain-details-of-docx4j-comparison)):

```
private static final String compareToSelf( File fileToCompare ) throws Docx4JException {
    WordprocessingMLPackage olderPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load( fileToCompare );
    WordprocessingMLPackage newerPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load( fileToCompare );

    Body newerBody = newerPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getJaxbElement().getBody();
    Body olderBody = olderPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getJaxbElement().getBody();

    java.io.StringWriter sw = new java.io.StringWriter();
    javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult result = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(sw);
    Calendar changeDate = null;

    Differencer pd = new Differencer();
    pd.setRelsDiffIdentifier("blagh"); // not necessary in this case
    pd.diff( newerBody, olderBody, result, "someone", changeDate,
                newerPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getRelationshipsPart(),
                olderPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getRelationshipsPart() );

    return sw.toString();
}
```

Stack trace:

```
com.topologi.diffx.xml.UndeclaredNamespaceException: The namespace URI "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office for allowincell" has not been mapped to any prefix.
    at com.topologi.diffx.xml.NSAwareXMLWriter.getQName(NSAwareXMLWriter.java:604)
    at com.topologi.diffx.xml.NSAwareXMLWriter.attribute(NSAwareXMLWriter.java:527)
    at com.topologi.diffx.event.impl.AttributeEventNSImpl.toXML(AttributeEventNSImpl.java:244)
    at com.topologi.diffx.format.SmartXMLFormatter.format(SmartXMLFormatter.java:212)
    at com.topologi.diffx.sequence.EventSequence.format(EventSequence.java:349)
    at com.topologi.diffx.Docx4jDriver.diff(Docx4jDriver.java:230)
    at org.docx4j.diff.Differencer.diffWorker(Differencer.java:320)
    at org.docx4j.diff.Differencer.diff(Differencer.java:298)
    at exec.DocxCompareTest.compareToSelf(DocxCompareTest.java:212)
    at exec.DocxCompareTest.handleInputFile(DocxCompareTest.java:124)
    at exec.ValidationTest.execute(ValidationTest.java:52)
    at exec.BtbRoundtripTest.main(BtbRoundtripTest.java:13)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.docx4j.diff.Differencer.diffWorker(Differencer.java:377)
    at org.docx4j.diff.Differencer.diff(Differencer.java:298)
    at exec.DocxCompareTest.compareToSelf(DocxCompareTest.java:212)
    at exec.DocxCompareTest.handleInputFile(DocxCompareTest.java:124)
    at exec.ValidationTest.execute(ValidationTest.java:52)
    at exec.BtbRoundtripTest.main(BtbRoundtripTest.java:13)
```

I've unzipped the *.docx file and the `o:allowincell` seems to be properly mapped with  `xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"` in the `<w:document>` tag of the contained `document.xml`.

Test document can be dowloaded from here: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6_h2TfqvEdeZE43X3RSWnFIZHc

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: This warning also appears during execution, unsure if it's relevant: `WARN  [org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager] - <DefaultPart used for part '/word/stylesWithEffects.xml' of content type 'application/vnd.ms-word.stylesWithEffects+xml'>`

Answer (score 0):

In Docx4jDriver at line 192 and 206 there is:

```
    e.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:w",
            "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
```

You probably need to add xmlns:o. Ultimately, that code needs to be improved to add all relevant namespaces automatically.